# Cannot open backup device Operating System error 5 (Access is denied)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to restore .bak file on **SQL Server 2014**, but it is not working. Initially, I tried:

1. On **SQL Server 2014**, right click on ***Databases*** -> ***Restore Database***
2. From Source, click on ***Device*** and chose the path to the .bak file

However, this did not work and nothing happened. When I was reading old SO posts to find a solution for this, someone had said I could use SQL command for it. So I tried the following command:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Student
    FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER2014\MSSQL\Backup\Student.bak'
```

However, this gives

> Cannot open backup device ''C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER2014\MSSQL\Backup\Student.bak'. Operating system error 5 (Access is denied) 
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally

When I SO'ed this error, I found some posts with the same issue. Someone said:

1. On **SQL Server 2014**, right click on ***Databases*** -> ***Restore Database***
2. Click on ***Files***
3. Fill the checkbox ***Relocate all files to folder***

will fix the issue, and this answer got many up-votes. However, on my SQL Server, this checkbox is grayed out and I cannot even check/uncheck it.

I also tried a way that many had mentioned:

1. Open **SQL Server 2014 Configuration Manager**
2. Change ***Log On As*** of ***SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER2014)*** to ***LocalSystem***

This also did not work. 
I am at a loss what to do to fix this problem. This problem started happening after I uninstalled and reinstalled **SQL Server 2014.** I had an installer, but I mistakenly selected ***Evaluation Mode*** about a month ago when I first installed it, and today I got an error message saying:

> Evaluation period has expired.

So I uninstalled **SQL Server 2014** and reinstalled it with ***EXPRESS Mode*** this time. Upon installation I got an error and I had to change the default name from ***MSSQLSERVER*** to ***MSSQLSERVER2014*** because I already had the folder of that name from the previous installation. So I am trying to restore the .bak file in ***MSSQLSERVER2014***.

Comment: Right-click on the file and check its permissions, permissions inheritance setting and file ownership.  Create a new database, take a backup and verify that you can restore it. Compare the security on the files.

Comment: To add/clarify to what @DavidBrowne-Microsoft has said: 1. By default SQL Server runs with restricted privileges. 2. "Program Files" is a restricted folder in Windows by default. 3. Solution: move your back file to the root of the C: drive e.g. "C:\Backups\" and then try to restore from that folder.